# How to clean messy time data using excel

Tags: excel, datetime, time, data-cleaning

I have a duration(time) data retrieved from a GPS system. The data shows the duration a player has played in the match. The problem is, for few records, the data is shown like 20:12(20 mins and 12 secs) and few records, it is shown as 20:12:00(20 mins, 12 secs, 00 ms).

Can I change all these records into secs format(as shown in the image attached)?

PS: I don't want to convert it into text format as I need to do some calculations and analysis with it.

TIA!

[[image: convert [h]:mm:ss to secs[1]]

Comment: What does `19:12` look like if you format the cell, `[hh]:mm:ss`?

Comment: The format for these records are like

19:12       - h:mm
..... 27:21:00 - [hh]:mm:ss

Comment: That was not my question, My question was; what does it look like if you change the format of the `19:12` from what it is to `[hh]:mm:ss`?

Comment: Thanks, @ScottCraner I have now changed all the records to [hh]:mm:ss format. Now, I need to convert these into seconds.

Comment: One last time, please show what it now look like.  is it `00:19:12` or is it `19:12:00`?

Comment: it is 19:12:00 now.

Comment: Then my answer will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
=TEXT(A2,"[hh]")*60 + MINUTE(A2)
```

Comment: when I applied `=TEXT(F2,"[hh]")*60 + MINUTE(F2)`

Gives me - **3/30/1900 0:00**

Comment: @vishnuprashanth Please mark the one you used as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer that you ended up using.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following User Defined Function:

```
Public Function secondz(r As Range) As Long
    Dim s As String, arr

    secondz = 0
    s = r(1).Text
    If InStr(s, ":") = 0 Then Exit Function
    arr = Split(s, ":")
    secondz = CLng(arr(0)) * 60 + CLng(arr(1))
End Function
```

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

```
=secondz(A1)
```

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Let me try to create this macro and will update you. Thanks!

Comment: I created the UDF and called the function `=secondz(A2)` and the answers are generated like 0:00

Maybe there is something to change/correct within the macro I guess.. I will check it :)

Comment: @vishnuprashanth  Please format the cell containing the formula to ***General***